# Reallocating template values throw __GI__ raise exception queue like array implementation exercise

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm messing up with some C++ exercises from a programming book I've been going through for a while. My task is to implement an linear data structure that expands itself twice its size when last insertion gets it full. I know there's a way to solve it with creating a temporal array to copy the values and transfer it back to the original starting array. However, I'd love to explore memory management with `malloc` `realloc` and the rest of it cause I'm curious about how to have deeper control over memory. My plan is to expand the solution of the exercise to shrink the array dynamically to apply the concept the other way around. That said I can effectively memory for my template value using `malloc` but unfortunately I'm unable to use `realloc` to make the array like structure larger. When debugging with gdb from Termdebug on Vim a `__GI__ raise` exception comes up. Frankly, I don't know what it means as it points out a .c file I don't know anything about.

Just to be sure that the issue is closely related to template values. I did a little test with int to check if there was something weird going on with the compiler.

I've got a feeling that c++ handles templates at runtime differently to primitive values but this is just a guess.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing? Is there a concept/reading/article/material I should learn?

Cheers!

```
/* Implement the structure "Circular Queue" with array, which doubles its capacity when it's 
 * full. Implement the necessary methods for adding, removing the element in succesion
 * and retrieving without removing the element in succession. If an operation is invalid,
 * throw an appropriate exception.*/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template <typename TValue>
class CQueue {
  public:
    CQueue();
    ~CQueue(); 
    void add(TValue data);
  private:
    size_t size = 1;
    TValue* array; 
};
template<typename TValue>
CQueue<TValue>::CQueue(){
  array = (TValue*) malloc(sizeof(TValue));
}

template<typename TValue>
CQueue<TValue>::~CQueue(){}

template<typename TValue>
void CQueue<TValue>::add(TValue data){
  if (*array == array[size-1]) {
    TValue* extend = NULL;
    extend = (TValue*)realloc(array, size*sizeof(TValue));
    if (extend!=NULL) {
      array = extend; 
      ++array;
    }else {
      free(array);
      puts("Error reallocation memory");
    }
  }
  *array = data;
}

int main(){
  CQueue<std::string>test; 
  test.add("data");
  test.add("Mafalda");
  test.add("lol");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `realloc` and `free` a pointer that points to the address originally returned by `malloc`. As soon as `++array;` happens you no longer have that. `if (*array == array[size-1])` doesn't make much sense. `size` doesn't increase in `add` so you realloc the same amount of memory you already had.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Based on it I'm gonna try to write a dedicated function to just enlarge the file and leave the adding and moving through the block to another function. I'll post the result if everything goes fine. BTW, it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

So, I was definitely moving the pointer memory reallocation as @RetiredNinja stated on his/her comment. Lesson learned here is to reproduce the problem better instead of just taking the first guess as the reason behind the problem :)

```
template<typename TValue>
void CQueue<TValue>::expand(){
  TValue* extend = NULL;
  extend = (TValue*)realloc(array, size*sizeof(TValue));
  if (extend!=NULL) {
    array = extend; 
  }else {
    free(array);
    puts("Error reallocation memory");
  }
}
```

Comment: You get bonus points for using a different pointer for the return value of `realloc`. :)

Comment: Hang on! So it's not a really bad idea after all but it always comes down to its case use right? Just curious

Comment: If you do `ptr = realloc(ptr, ...)` and it fails the original allocation is leaked becaue you've lost the pointer to it. You're handling that possibility correctly. What to do next is situational and dealing with an out of memory condition is always tricky.. You could not free `array` but right now there's no way for the caller to know it failed so it'll probably write past the end of the previous allocation. Freeing it just means the whole queue is unusable, and not setting it to `NULL` after freeing it would be a problem if the destructor tried to free it later.

Comment: Hey @RetiredNinja! Sorry about my late reply, got caught working on a frontend project. I came across with more issues with using the array exclusively so I incorporated an extra pointer. I'd lie to try return a different pointer for the return value to fully understand what you meant with your last comment. I got it partially so seeing it in code will let me understand better. Have a good one! \m/